# iptable rule for INPUT with specific destination ip not getting blocked and iptable is not aware of any such packet at all

Tags: iptables, firewall

Most of the concerns are for SRC ip in case of INPUT chain.

However for below case:

**Below works if someone send wrong src ip or wrong dest port:**

IP of one of interface in host is 192.168.1.11

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1 -d 192.168.1.11 -dport 1000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j NFLOG --nflog-group 30
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

**Below doest not works** if someone send wrong src ip or wrong dest port:

**There is no IP - 192.168.1.11 to any of interface in host**

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1 -d 192.168.1.11 -dport 1000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j NFLOG --nflog-group 30
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

This gives impression:

- having unregister IP in host ( no iface with specific IP), makes iptable to not to consider that rule at all
  Or
- iptable will never receive this incoming pcket at all and its get dropped before it.

iptables comes later stage after routing of IPs.

Can anyone let me know if this is how iptable works?

Also what is the way to overcome it in case intention is to log in NFLOG about any incoming message getting in system which describe wrong destinmation IP.

I had tried, -t mangle, -t nat, -A preroute and also string check.

Do i need ot use lower level checks e.g. ebtable, NetFilter etc.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no IP - 192.168.1.11 to any of interface in host
>
> This gives impression: -- having unregister IP in host ( no iface with specific IP), makes iptable to not to consider that rule at all

Step back, ignore iptables, and consider why would the computer accept and process the packet at all?  If you completely disabled all the firewall rules what would happen?

If a computer doesn't have an IP associated with a given interface, and you haven't done anything unusual, then it isn't even going to reply to the ARP packet with the mac address. So the packet would never even be processed by the computer in the first place.